# Common bold command for Latin and Greek letters

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, bold

Following this post, [Bold math: Automatic choice between \mathbf and \boldsymbol for Latin and Greek symbols?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3535/bold-math-automatic-choice-between-mathbf-and-boldsymbol-for-latin-and-greek), I created the command

```
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{\mathbf{#1}}}
```

and include

```
\usepackage{bm}.
```

In a previous paper I wrote this worked great.  The greek symbols were bold and the normal Latin letters were bold roman (not italic).  I am writing my thesis now with a template provided by our department and using this command doesn't work (you use the command and everything shows up non-bold, non-italics roman.) Removing the \mathbf from the command so it is just

```
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
```

makes it so it at least bolds everything, but the Latin letters are now italicized. The only possible clue I see in the log file is a warning that say "There are no bold math fonts."

Any ideas on where to look to see what would cause this?

Comment: Can you identify what all font packages (both math and text) does the template use?

Comment: It uses amsmath, amssymb, mathptmx, textcomp, and I added bm.  Also, I just found that if in the original command I replace \boldsymbol with \pmb, it appears to work.

Comment: `\pmb` works, but it's completely incorrect (and very noticeably uglu). The problem here is very likely in `mathptmx`.

Comment: @tohecz you are correct--I just found these posts: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117076/how-can-i-get-bold-greek-letters-with-mathptmx and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20025/is-there-any-way-other-than-pmb-to-produce-bold-greek-letters-when-mathptmx-is which makes it pretty clear that mathptmx is the problem.  I also have to agree that \pmb is ugly.