# y-label shows up twice in pgfplot when the bm package is used?

Tags: pgfplots, bm

Can you tell me if it is possible to remove this extra y-label so that it looks cleaner?  In my code below, I get the y-label showing up twice like:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotsset{minor grid style={dotted,gray!90}}
\pgfplotsset{major grid style={gray!70!black},
            every tick label/.append style={font=\scriptsize},
            every axis plot/.append style={line width=0.8pt},
            }


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogxaxis}[width=14cm,height=10.2cm,
                    grid = both,
                    log ticks with fixed point,
                    x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=\,},
                    every major grid/.style={gray, opacity=0.9},
                    %ymin =  -60,
                    %ymax = 7,
                    %xmin = 0.01,
                    %xmax = 100,
                    title = {},
                    xlabel={Test},
                    ylabel={$\bm{20 log \mid E(s)\mid (dB)}$},
                    no markers,
                    every axis plot/.append style={very thick},
                    legend style={at={(0,1)},anchor=north west},
                    legend cell align=left,
                    ]

\addplot+ {rand};

\end{semilogxaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Alenanno, that changes the font.  Is it possible to keep the original font?

Comment: I think that it is Times?

Comment: If font hasn't bold version, `bm` replace it with poor man's bold (print text twice, slightly shifted) .

Comment: I think I completely skipped over the title. :D Sorry, I removed my obsolete comments.

Comment: Unrelated comment: Use `\log`, not `log`, for the logarithm. Then the operator is printed upright, as it's supposed to be.

Comment: Your (math) fonts are mathptmx, which hasn't bold version, so `$\bm{....}$ is made with poor man's bold. This is known issue.  See, if http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20025/is-there-any-way-other-than-pmb-to-produce-bold-greek-letters-when-mathptmx-is solve your problem.

Comment: @Zarko -- please make your last comment an answer.  that seems more appropriate than closing the question.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, I convert my comment to answer. Thank you to encourage me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your math fonts are mathptmx, which hasn't bold version, so `$\bm{....}$` is made with poor man's bold (normal letters are slightly shifted printed twice). This is known issue.

As solution you can do (stolen from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20025/is-there-any-way-other-than-pmb-to-produce-bold-greek-letters-when-mathptmx-is))

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\SetSymbolFont{letters}{bold}{OML}{cmm}{b}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{cmr}{bx}{n}
```

or use other fonts with bold math.